# Xubuntu 14.04 Change Xfce Login and Lockscreen Button Color

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce, login-screen, lock-screen

I have Xubuntu 14.04, and I would like to change the login and lock screen button color from blue to green without changing the theme. However, I can't seem to find the proper configuration file to do so. Thank you.
[Here is a screenshot.](http://xubuntu.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/xubuntu_lock_light-locker.png)

Comment: I don't think there's a config file that can do this. You need to edit the images if you want to make them green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Appearance > Style, I am using Orion. I believe similar steps would apply for any theme.

```
sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

Then I changed this line to Orion: `theme-name=Orion`

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Orion/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

Then I changed this line to my custom green hexadecimal number:

```
@define-color selected_bg_color #94C565;
```

I logged out and the button is now green.